# Endogeneity problem

Tags: panel-data, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

I am doing a panel random effects model for estimating the relationship between remittances and poverty. My results are significant. But literature suggests there may be a problem of endogeneity or reverse causality between remittances and poverty. 
So i use an Instrumental Variable i.e. distance from remittance sending to receiving country and run an `xtivreg` regression (in Stata) but my results are insignificant. Even though first stage suggests that it is a valid IV. 
Any suggestion on how to deal with it or any other way of controlling for endogeneity?

Comment: This is way too broad to be answerable. What is your model, what variable do you think is endogenous and why? Is it constant over time or does it vary?

Comment: Please clarify your question and narrow its scope by making edits in your question.

Comment: @Glen_b...Done.

Comment: This might get better answers on the [Economics Q&A site](http://economics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Econometrics questions are perfectly well suited for CV. This one is just very badly phrased such that it is hard to answer. After the edit it now seems more of a duplicate of the usual "why are my IV results insignificant" question.