# Bayesian Hierarchical Regression Models for Panel Data

Tags: regression, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I am fairly comfortable with Bayesian hierarchical regression models, but I am new to panel data analysis. As someone from the social sciences, I have found that the majority of resources on panel data come from econometrics, which can be confusing. The terminology, particularly the distinction between 'Fixed' and 'Random' effects models, differs from what I am used to. An yes, I've read several threads on this website detailing the difference.

In my view, panel data is well-suited for 'Hierarchical' regression models because each individual is measured at least twice, making it logical to introduce varying intercepts to the model. For example, in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238214/how-exactly-does-a-random-effects-model-in-econometrics-relate-to-mixed-models), I would assume the following model:

$$y_{it} = \beta X_{it} + u_i + \epsilon_{it}$$

where $u_i$ represents the varying intercept across people (although I would probably express $u_i$ as $a_i$, but that's beside the point).

However, I have come across materials that suggest that if $u_i$ is correlated with observed predictors, this model should not be used (although I still don't fully understand why). But I don't see how this assumption is any different from clustering on countries or any other hierarchical structure. It is an incredibly strong assumption that probably does not hold, so is everyone who uses hierarchical regression models simply wrong?

Comment: To answer your secondary question (why 'random effects' models should not be used when $u_i$ and $X_{it}$ are correlated): these correlations hint at the presence of omitted variables, measurement errors of the predictors, and/or simultaneity between the predictors and predicted variable. In short, you're [dealing with endogeneity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/151698). For more details on this problem, see [Antonakis et al. (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1177/1094428119877457) or [their brief discussion of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcwjto0U01I).